# Control Center-like sliding view implementation in Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, control-center

I'm trying to create an interactive sliding transition on App.

The goal is to present a uiview when view controller that will be dragged from the bottom(not from the bottom edge so it won't conflict with the control center) and will partially cover the main view controller (just like the iOS control center). The transition should be interactive, i.e according to the dragging of the user.

Would be happy to hear ideas regarding available APIs.

Comment: I have done this before, I don't have the code on me but I could send it over when I get home should you still be without an answer.

Comment: Thanks @JacobKing for your quick response, i am waiting for your answer.

Comment: @JacobKing can you please share the code

Comment: @user6520705 I don't work for the company anymore so I don't have access to their source control repository... It's possible I have an old local copy but I doubt it, will look when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will do the simple slideView animation code tested in Xcode 8 and worked..

```
 import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

// I am using VisualView as a slideView
@IBOutlet weak var slideView: UIVisualEffectView!

//Button to open slideView
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // setting background for sideView
       slideView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "original.jpg")!)

    //Initial hide so it won't show.when the mainView loads...
      slideView.isHidden = true

    // DownSwipe to hide slideView
       let downSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleSwipes(_:)))
       downSwipe.direction = .down
       view.addGestureRecognizer(downSwipe)
    }

   // set UIButton to open slideVie...(I am using UIBarButton)
     @IBAction func sdrawButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {

      self.slideView.isHidden = false
      slideView.center.y += view.frame.height

      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations:{
        self.slideView.center.y -= self.view.frame.height
        self.button.isEnabled = false
        }, completion: nil)  
}

   func handleSwipes(_ sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if (sender.direction == .down) {
        print("Swipe Down")

        self.slideView.isHidden = true

        self.slideView.center.y -= self.view.frame.height
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations:{
            self.slideView.center.y += self.view.frame.height
            self.button.isEnabled = true
            }, completion: nil)
  }  
  }
  }
```

Let me know the code works for you...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this question is a bit old. 
You can subclass a UIView and override touchesBegan(_ , with) to save the original touch location

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
  guard let  touch = touches.first else { print("No touch"); return }
      startPoint = touch.location(in: self)
      startHeight = heightConstraint.constant
      slideDirection = .none
      super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
   }
```

}

and touchesMoved(_,with) to update the Height constraint while a finger is sliding the view.

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
  guard let touch = touches.first else { print("touchesMovedno touches"); return }

  let endPoint = touch.location(in: self)
  let diff = endPoint.y - startPoint.y

  // This causes the view to move along the drag
  switch anchorLocation {
  case .top :
     heightConstraint.constant = startHeight + diff
  case .bottom :
     heightConstraint.constant = startHeight - diff
  }
  self.layoutIfNeeded()

  // Update direction
  if diff == 0.0 {
     self.slideDirection = .none
  } else {
     self.slideDirection = (diff > 0) ? .down : .up
  }
  super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
```

}

Override touchesEnded(_, with) to add animation if you wish

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

  self.modifyHeightConstraints()
  self.animateViewTransition(duration: animDuration, delay: animDelay, clearance: animClearance, springDampingRatio: animSpringDampingRatio, initialSpringVelocity: animInitialSpringVelocity, complete: {
     self.slideDirection = .none
  })
  super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
```

}

I have created a component that might have the exact feature you wanted. The component includes adjustable animated bouncing. You can layout and design subviews on the view in storyboard.

Check out the link in GitHub

https://github.com/narumolp/NMPAnchorOverlayView